# Android: Multiple Alarm not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-ndk, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In My application i have set the two alarm.
On toogleButton on i am going to set it on with below code:

```
case R.id.toggleButtonTwoMonth:
            myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            if (tButtonTwoMonth.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Two months reminder is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); prefsEditor.putBoolean("TwoMonth", true); prefsEditor.commit(); 

                //For Broadcast Alarm
                Intent in = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);

                alarmManagerForTwoMonth1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth2 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                pendingIntentOfTwoMonth1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                pendingIntentOfTwoMonth2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                // ===================== GST ALARM FOR THE TWO MONTHS ==========================

                // for the GST 20 June 2011
                Calendar calendar_GST_18_June_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.set(2011, 5, 18, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth1);

                // for the GST 17 August 2011

                Calendar calendar_GST_17_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 17,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntentOfTwoMonth2);


            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Two months reminder is Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); prefsEditor.putBoolean("TwoMonth", false); prefsEditor.commit();

                //alarmManagerForTwoMonth.cancel(pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);
            }
            break;
```

But i am not getting the amarm notification at that desire time and if the toggle is on.
Now after time of alarm is passaway and if i doing toggle off and then on so i get the alarm.

So whats wrong with my Code ?
Please help me for that.

**EDITED:**

With thia answer i have solve to set the alarm for multiple time: [How can I setup multiple alarms in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273342/how-can-i-setup-multiple-alarms-in-android)

But i am wondering about how to get it handle. I mean how to handle that alarm on receiver with different message ?

My updated Code with the Multiple Alarm is below:

```
//For Broadcast Alarm
                Intent in = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);

                // ===================== GST ALARM FOR THE TWO MONTHS ==========================

                // for the GST 20 June 2011
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                pendingIntentOfTwoMonth1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_18_June_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.set(2011, 5, 18, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth1);

                // for the GST 17 August 2011
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth2 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                pendingIntentOfTwoMonth2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_17_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 17,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManagerForTwoMonth2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntentOfTwoMonth2);
```

And the Code for the Receiver is like below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // My Notification Code
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.app_icon;

    CharSequence text = "Your tax amount due period";
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Tax Calculator App";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("the Date is: "+(cal.getTime().getDate())+" "+ (cal.getTime().getMonth())+" "+  (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

    if((cal.getTime().getDate()==18) && (cal.getTime().getMonth()==5) && (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)==2011)){
        contentText = "Your GST tax amount is due on 20 June 2011";
    }
    else if((cal.getTime().getDate()==17) && (cal.getTime().getMonth()==7) && (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)==2011)){
        contentText = "Your GST tax amount is due on 19th August, 2011";
    }
    else{
        contentText = "Your GST tax amount is due on Falana Dhikna Date";
    } 

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    intent = new Intent(context, NotificationViewer.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification = new Notification(icon,text,when);

    long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
    notification.vibrate = vibrate;  // To vibrate the Device

    notification.ledARGB = Color.RED;
    notification.ledOffMS = 300;
    notification.ledOnMS = 300;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


}
```

Now how to handle that different alarm ??
Help me for this.
Thanks.

**Edited**

Pleasee this code:

```
case R.id.toggleButtonTwoMonth:
            myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            if (tButtonTwoMonth.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Two months reminder is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); prefsEditor.putBoolean("TwoMonth", true); prefsEditor.commit(); 

                //For Broadcast Alarm
                //Intent in = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);

                // ===================== GST ALARM FOR THE TWO MONTHS ==========================

                // for the GST 20 June 2011
                AM_2M_GST_1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in1.putExtra("MyMessage","Your GST tax is due on 20 June 2011");
                PI_2M_GST_1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_18_June_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.set(2011, 5, 18, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_GST_1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis(), PI_2M_GST_1);

                // for the GST 19 August 2011
                AM_2M_GST_2 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in2 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in2.putExtra("MyMessage","Your GST tax is due on 19 August 2011");
                PI_2M_GST_2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, in2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_17_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 17,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_GST_2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_2);

                // for the GST 19 October 2011  
                AM_2M_GST_3 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in3 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in3.putExtra("MyMessage","Your GST tax is due on 19 October 2011");
                PI_2M_GST_3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, in3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_19_October_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_19_October_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_19_October_2011.set(2011, 9, 19,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_GST_3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_19_October_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_3);

                // for the GST 17 December 2011 
                AM_2M_GST_4 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in4 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in4.putExtra("MyMessage","Your GST tax is due on 17 December 2011");
                PI_2M_GST_4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, in4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_17_December_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_17_December_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_17_December_2011.set(2011, 11, 17,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_GST_4.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_December_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_4);

                // for the GST 20 February 2012 
                AM_2M_GST_5 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in5 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in5.putExtra("MyMessage","Your GST tax is due on 18 February 2012");
                PI_2M_GST_5 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, in5, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_18_February_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_18_February_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_18_February_2012.set(2012, 1, 18,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_GST_5.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_18_February_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_5);

                // for the GST 27 April 2012    
                AM_2M_GST_6 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in6 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in6.putExtra("MyMessage","Your GST tax is due on 27 April 2012");
                PI_2M_GST_6 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 5, in6, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_GST_27_April_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_27_April_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_27_April_2012.set(2012, 3, 27,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_GST_6.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_27_April_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_6);

                // ===================== PROVISIONAL ALARM FOR THE TWO MONTHS ==========================

                // for the PROVISIONAL 26 August 2011   
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in7 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in7.putExtra("MyMessage","Your PROVISIONAL tax is due on 26 August 2011");
                PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 6, in7, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_PROVISIONAL_26_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_PROVISIONAL_26_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_PROVISIONAL_26_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 26,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_PROVISIONAL_26_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_1);

                // for the PROVISIONAL 13 January 2012  
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_2 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in8 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in8.putExtra("MyMessage","Your PROVISIONAL tax is due on 13 January 2012");
                PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 7, in8, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_PROVISIONAL_13_January_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_PROVISIONAL_13_January_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_PROVISIONAL_13_January_2012.set(2012, 0, 13,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_PROVISIONAL_13_January_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_2);

                // for the PROVISIONAL 5 May 2012   
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_3 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in9 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in9.putExtra("MyMessage","Your PROVISIONAL tax is due on 5 May 2012");
                PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 8, in9, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_PROVISIONAL_5_May_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_PROVISIONAL_5_May_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_PROVISIONAL_5_May_2012.set(2012, 4, 5,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_PROVISIONAL_5_May_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_3);

                // ===================== TERMINAL ALARM FOR THE TWO MONTHS ==========================

                // for the TERMINAL 5 April 2012    
                AM_2M_TERMINAL_1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in10 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in10.putExtra("MyMessage","Your TERMINAL tax is due on 5 APRIL 2012");
                PI_2M_TERMINAL_1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 9, in10, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar_TERMINAL_5_APRIL_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_TERMINAL_5_APRIL_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_TERMINAL_5_APRIL_2012.set(2012, 3, 5,mHour, mMinute, 0);
                AM_2M_TERMINAL_1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_TERMINAL_5_APRIL_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_TERMINAL_1);

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Two months reminder is Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); prefsEditor.putBoolean("TwoMonth", false); prefsEditor.commit();

                AM_2M_GST_1.cancel(PI_2M_GST_1);
                AM_2M_GST_2.cancel(PI_2M_GST_2);
                AM_2M_GST_3.cancel(PI_2M_GST_3);
                AM_2M_GST_4.cancel(PI_2M_GST_4);
                AM_2M_GST_5.cancel(PI_2M_GST_5);
                AM_2M_GST_6.cancel(PI_2M_GST_6);
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_1.cancel(PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_1);
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_2.cancel(PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_2);
                AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_3.cancel(PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_3);
                AM_2M_TERMINAL_1.cancel(PI_2M_TERMINAL_1);

                //alarmManagerForTwoMonth.cancel(pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);
            }
            break;
```

Now. here i got the Notification. but i want it seperate for all. Means if there is one already exist and if new is generated then it should not be update the already present but should have to create new seperate of it.
Thanks.

Comment: r u using sqlite database(Internal Database) for save the alarm and use broadcast receiver for get the alarm notification.

Comment: No I am not using any database for it. . . why ? should i have to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Why don't you do this

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
in.putExtra("MyMessage","Your tax is due on blah blah blah");
pendingIntentOfTwoMonth1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And in the `onRecieve`

Simply Retrieve the message from the Intent

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// blah blah
   Toast.show(context,intent.getStringExtra("MyMessage"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Ok So if i use it for my code then will it be work as i want ?

Comment: Yes, When setting your alarm, Use the intent to store data about the event...In your Broadcast Reciever, simply retrive the data from that Intent (2nd Parameter of `onRecieve`) it's the same one you created while setting the alarm

Comment: I got syntext error at intent that the variable is not resolved

Comment: Yes your code works great. Now what if i dont want to update the alarm notification and got the every notification for its own. I mean right now if there is already any notification and if i got another notification then the new notification will updated on the past one.   So if i want seperate notification for all then what should i have to do ?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer, Use a different requestCode for each one, see the `0` parameter in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call? That should be different for each distinct alarm.

Comment: Yes i have done like that. But i want is to generate the different notification. right now it is updating the previous one if previous one is stil exist in the notification bar.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer, Post your Code.

Comment: Ok I have solve it. I am using same notification id for all. I have change the Notification ID for all and it works nice. . .

Comment: @iDroidExplorer, That's what i told you 2 comments ago.

Answer (score 1):

Plz try my answer from following link using database.

[AlarmManager with Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357469/how-can-i-get-the-repeat-alarm-for-week-days-using-alarm-manager-in-android/7358365#7358365)

First Add Alarm Time and date into database from your activity & then create broadcast receiver class for get the data from database.

Comment: So If i want to make the Multiple Alarm for selecting day then i have to use the Database to use that selected date ?

Comment: But if i use the Single Alatm with selected date and time then it works then why not for other date is works ?

Comment: In Inbuilt Alarm only Single alarm is work if u use the database for multiple alarm that is worked for me from above link.

Comment: I just want to make the Different Alam on different Date. . .  And with this i can get it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273342/how-can-i-setup-multiple-alarms-in-android

Comment: I have to set alarm for next 17 days and 4 times a day. To set multiple alarm at same time with single method call was not working, but by using unique id to the pending intent 2nd parameter it works fine for me. Thanks. Pls check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858366/how-to-set-multiple-alarms-in-android-last-alarm-overwrites-preveious-alarms-in