# How to set a recurring AlarmManager to execute code on a scheduled date?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am making a medicine reminder app which reminds people to take their medicine on a scheduled date-time.

For example, if my  **start-date is 08-APR-2013 and the end-date is 12-APR-2013 and time is 11.30 am  then the alarm should fire till 12-APR-2013 at 11.30 am.**
Please help with how I can achieve this. I know how to set an alarm manager and the normal alarm is fired. But when I have a start-date and end-date at that time I become confused about how I should use the `alarmManager.setRepeating()` method.

Comment: I think you have to use 'set()' if you want to set it for an exact date instead of 'setRepeating()' http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: hey i will try the code the way you suggest. i hope i'll get the things the way i want..!!

Comment: hey thanks for suggestion its almost done..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code for repeating alarm for every day

```
Date dateobj=new Date(Year,month,day,hour,min);             
setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateobj.getTime(), (24*60*60*1000), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: i want to repeat the alarm till my end-date came. above code will work on my requirements?

Comment: if you want to schedule only four days setrepeting concept doesn't work.use different request code with different timings

Comment: then how should i set my alarm?

Comment: Date dateobj=new Date(Year,month,day,hour,min); // increment by day
Intent intent1= new Intent(CurrentClass.this,service.class);//service or broadcast
pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(ScheduleManagement.this,1, intent1,3);//change the request code every time  set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateobj.getTime(), pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by setting the alarm at the time you want by using the setReapting() method.

```
1.Use a table to insert your entries.
2.query the table for every minute or for the time interval you want using a broadcast receiver.
3.In the onReceive() callback compare the current time with the insert time and fire the alarm.
4.if there is no record then cancel the pending intent.
```

if you have any doubt in this go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357469/how-can-i-get-the-repeat-alarm-for-week-days-using-alarm-manager-in-android)

.