# Create alarm using AlarmManager and BroadcastReciver

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

How to create an alarm using AlarmManager and BroadcastReciver to allow scheduling alarm within several days of the week (e.g. Sunday, Monday, Wednesday and Friday) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i set an alarm manager to fire every on specific day of week and time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601678/how-do-i-set-an-alarm-manager-to-fire-every-on-specific-day-of-week-and-time-in)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these links below describe will solve your problem:

1. [how can i get the repeat alarm for week days using alarm manager in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357469/how-can-i-get-the-repeat-alarm-for-week-days-using-alarm-manager-in-android)
2. https://www.journaldev.com/27681/android-alarmmanager-broadcast-receiver-and-service

Comment: follow this link for the full source code: https://github.com/PPartisan/Simple-Alarms